# How to give slot to Svelte component constructor

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to start using Svelte into an old app that is built by something else.

I created `MyBlock.svelte` like this, and set up the compiler.

```html
<div class="MyBlock">
  <slot />
</div>

<style>
  .MyBlock {
    border: thin solid tomato;
  }
</style>
```

I'd like to apply the MyBlock component to this HTML...

```html
<div id="target">
  Hello World!
</div>
```

...by the JavaScript code below, but I got an error.

```js
const target = document.querySelector("#target");
new MyBlock({
  props: {
    $$slots: { default: target.childNodes },
  },
  target,
})
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ctx')
```

The error comes from `node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs` over compiled MyBlock code.

What value is proper for `$$slots`? Is there document how to invoke Svelte component constructor by `new`?

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported. Any attempt to try and set slots programmatically can only be achieved using private, undocumented APIs. See [this open issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2588).